# Navigation settings changed but not applied

Tags: development

I have this in mij feature which is activated after the creation of a site

```
PublishingWeb pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
WebNavigationSettings navsettings = new WebNavigationSettings(web);
navsettings.GlobalNavigation.Source = StandardNavigationSource.InheritFromParentWeb;

pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentIncludeSubSites = false;
pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentIncludePages = false;
pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentDynamicChildLimit = 20;

navsettings.Update();
pubWeb.Update();
web.Update();
```

The problem is that the settings are changed.
When I brwose to the navigation settings of the site they are changed.
If a click ok whitout changing anything it works.

If I press cancel nothing changes.

Somebody ?